# hacking p5js canvas to enable shadows

Tags: javascript, 3d, html5-canvas, webgl, p5.js

I'm having this small test project in p5.js

https://editor.p5js.org/derDere/sketches/42je_Mgwt

It contains some random boxes a spot light showing the center and a point light at the center to show some box walls.

as you can see the boxes are casting no shadow which makes it look like the point light is shining thru the walls.

according to this issue shadows in p5.js are not a thing

https://github.com/processing/p5.js/issues/3167

according to the Dev its not necessary to create a wrapper to make shadows in p5js.

I get that p5.js is a library for beginners so I get the point.

but I would like to have some shadows inside this project anyway so does anyone know how I could "hack" the script to make this possible without chaining the current part of this script?

Comment: There are dozens of ways to implement shadows. The best method will depend on how you view the model, the type of lights casting shadows, if you are animating any components involved in the shadows, and the quality and attributes of the shadows. Even the simplest shadows will require a lot of code and an advanced understanding of 3D and webGL. I suggest for the inexperienced rather than start from the ground up use a library more suited to the task (has shadows built in).

Comment: As blindman67 says shadows in WebGL are pretty involved. See [this article](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-shadows.html) which has 7 articles of prerequisites and those articles themsevles about 15 more. Read those if you want to add shadows to p5 or consider using [a library](https://threejs.org) that has [shadows built in](https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/lessons/threejs-shadows.html).

Comment: Code should be in the question itself as a [mcve] so that stale links won't harm its usefulness to future visitors.